# How to get build start time inside a build step in teamcity?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, devops, teamcity

I'm having multiple build steps, in one of which I need to retrieve the starting time of the when the entire build was triggered, is there any way to get it ? Are there any parameters or way to retrieve it from logs, live from a build step without additional plugin or script or even from environment ?

Currently I'm adding
echo "Build triggered at $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" as a place holder for my purpose but I need the actual build triggered time.

Comment: JFYI Build triggered time and build start time could be different if build was in queue waiting for free agent.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find property which contains actual start time.

Workaround is to make a REST API request inside of build step

```http
GET {{TEAMCITY_HOST}}/app/rest/builds/id:%teamcity.build.id%
    ?fields=startDate,finishDate
Authorization: Bearer {{TC_API_TOKEN}}
Accept: application/json
```

`%teamcity.build.id%` - you can access current build id (not build number) via [predefined build parameters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/predefined-build-parameters.html#Predefined+Server+Build+Parameters).

`{{TEAMCITY_HOST}}` - substitute your TeamCity domain (e.g. `https://myteamcity.com`)

`{{TC_API_TOKEN}}` - could be gained via user profile settings. Do not insert it as a plain text, use [password build parameters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/typed-parameters.html#Adding+Parameter+Specification).